# PostBackUrl and Form Action download php page instead of redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, forms, postbackurl

My aspx pages react normally when it comes to using Response.Redirect(".php") or a href='.php' to external web resource. However, when it comes to using PostBackUrl = ".php" or form action=".php" they download file instead of opening it.

How can I make them redirect users to external .php resources as they should, instead of downloading .php files?

Comment: Are you putting the full absolute path to the external resource? show any code?

Comment: Solved by Darren! Apparently, for some reason, if you specify a link in otherwise correct format in PostBackUrl or Form Action without "www" it downloads in this case specifically ".php" resource instead of redirecting to it which it does with "www" included.